# Run 2 function same times in unit test for IOS

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I have a question about run functions same times in unit test.

I have 1 array A is global in ViewContronller.

- 1 function B to update data to this array.
- 1 function C use this array to filter.

Problem:
App crashed when App calling function C to filter while function B updating. If function C is filtering at same time with function B update data of Array A. => App crash with reason "Array was mutated while being enumerated"

I don't know, I can or I can't write unit test to them.Please help me check about above case.How can reproduce crash in unit test?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing something like this.

```
for (id object in myArray)
   if (someCondition)
       [myArray removeObject:object]
```

You can't edit a mutable array while you're going through it so you need to make a temporary array to hold the things you want to remove/modify.